# Dynamic rendering of page using p:layout

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to dynamically load a page based on selected action in a p:layout - my action is driven by a managed bean - using the code below I see the managed bean getting called and the correct page gets passed but does not get rendered. Wondering what I am missing, hoping someone can point it out.

Thanks

### Layout Page

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
      <f:view contentType="text/html" locale="en">
  <h:head title="Title">
        <ui:insert name="head" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" header="Top"
             resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" header="Bottom"
                  resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
    </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" style="width:200px"
               header="Menu" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
        <h:form id="formMainMenu">
    <p:panelMenu style="width:400px">
    <p:submenu label="Sub Menu 1">
    <p:submenu label="Sub Menu 2" icon="ui-icon-extlink">
    <p:menuitem value="Option1" 
       actionListener="#{menuController.setPage('../../public/pages/aboutTest.xhtml')}"
         update=":allLayoutForm:allLayout" />
       </p:submenu>
       </p:submenu>
   </p:panelMenu>
   </h:form>
     </p:layoutUnit>


     <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200" header="Right"
       resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true" effect="fade">
 </p:layoutUnit>
 <h:form id="allLayoutForm">
       <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="allLayout">
    <ui:insert name="content">src="#{menuController.page}"</ui:insert>
 </p:layoutUnit>
</h:form>
    </p:layout>
</h:body>
    </f:view>
    </html>
```

### Menu Controller

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MenuController {

private String page;

public String getPage() {
    System.out.println(" Get "+page);
    return page;
}

public void setPage(String page) {
    System.out.println(page);
    this.page = page;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have some static part of your html page used everywhere in your application you should take a look to JSF template ([example here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/)).

MainTemplate.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title><ui:insert name="title">Default title</ui:insert></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="menuForm">
            <p:menubar model="#{bean.menumodel}" />
        </h:form>
        <ui:insert name="content" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And for all your page going to look like this :

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" 
    template="/templates/MainTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">Title Page</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
    /* your jsf code */
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

With this example you could change content and title of your pages easily.